# Compare Calendar and java.util.date dates

Tags: java, date

Hi i am creating instance of Calendar Using:

```
Calendar calendarDate=Calendar.getInstance();
            calendarDate.set(2012, 6, 1,0,0,0);
                Date date1=calendar.getTime();
```

After that i create instance of java.util.date using:

```
Date date2=new Date(2012 - 1900,7-1, 01);
```

Now when i am trying to compare dates using following code:

```
System.out.println(date2.compareTo(date1));
System.out.println(date1.compareTo(date2));
```

it prints -1 and 1 instead of 0(zero).
**Can any one help me to find what's goes wrong ?**

Comment: there is no javascript here, removing the tag.

Comment: Have you printed out the two values themselves?

Comment: they are different dates... (2012-06-01 and 2012-07-01)

Comment: @Francisco No they are not two difference dates both represent 2012-07-01.

Comment: @Jon yes I printed those value

Comment: @Vipul: That means you have more information that you didn't include in the question...

Comment: @Jon sorry I forgot to add : Date date1=calendar.getTime(); in first code block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to clear the value of calendar before set a new one. This will solve your problem.

```
Calendar calendarDate=Calendar.getInstance();
calendarDate.clear();
calendarDate.set(2012, 6, 1,0,0,0);
```

Test for it:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import org.junit.Assert;

public class DateTest {

    @org.junit.Test
    public void test() {
        Calendar calendarDate=Calendar.getInstance();
        calendarDate.clear();
        calendarDate.set(2012, 6, 1,0,0,0);
        Assert.assertEquals(0, calendarDate.getTime().compareTo(new Date(2012 - 1900,7-1, 01)));
    }

}
```

Comment: In calendar,  6 represent Calendar.July

Comment: yes, I just add a clear, please clear it before set and you will see it works

Answer (score 2):

Date and Calender classes are different. Most of the methods of java.util.Date  are deprecated. Hence its better to use Calender class. For more info on methods check out the below url.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#compareTo(java.lang.Object)

compareTo

Returns:
the value 0 if the argument is a Date equal to this Date; a value less than 0 if the argument is a Date after this Date; and a value greater than 0 if the argument is a Date before this Date.

Answer (score 0):

Dates are GMT except when using the deprecated constructors.  There will be a difference here because you also need to set the milli-seconds to 0 as well.

```
Calendar calendarDate=Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
calendarDate.set(2012, Calendar.JULY, 1,0,0,0);
calendarDate.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
Date date1 = calendarDate.getTime();
Date date2=new Date(2012 - 1900,7-1, 1, 1, 0, 0);
System.out.println(date1);
System.out.println(date2);
System.out.println(date2.compareTo(date1));
System.out.println(date1.compareTo(date2));
```

prints

```
Sun Jul 01 01:00:00 BST 2012
Sun Jul 01 01:00:00 BST 2012
0
0
```

Note: Calendar will leave any field you don't set so the first set() will leave the milliseconds untouched.

Comment: Nope, the `Date` constructor uses the local time zone as well, awfully enough. While it's true that `Date` itself is always "milliseconds since the UTC Unix Epoch" it goes through the same default time zone when using the deprecated constructors.

Answer (score 0):

where is date1 created? You seem to assume Calendar and Date are related. They are not.

Comment: date1 is created using : Date date1 = calendar.getTime();